# Android Home Shortcut loses flags after reboot

Tags: java, android, shortcut

My Android app defines an activity with an intent filter of android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT, which lets me show up in the list of shortcuts that the user can add to their home page, when they select "Add Shortcut" from the menu or long-click the home page.

In this activity I have the following code (actually happens in a click event after they pick which shortcut to add):

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.myicon);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "MyAppName");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); 
finish();
```

The shortcut works as I would expect, until I reboot the device.  I'm actually testing on the emulator, not real device.  The shortcut is still there after a reboot, so I know I didn't wipe user data or anything like that, but it acts like it no longer has the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK setting when clicked.

Example steps to recreate (assume my app is an email inbox for clarity):

1. Create the shortcut
2. Launch my inbox activity from my main menu acitvity, which uses the NEW_TASK flag.
3. From the inbox activity, click a message to open the view message activity.
4. Press HOME key
5. Click the shortcut -- at this point it brings the entire "task stack" back to the front, with the view message activity on top of the stack, clicking back goes back to the inbox activity, as I would expect
6. Reboot the device
7. Repeat steps 2 through 5.. now when I click the shortcut, instead of bringing the view message activity to the front, it brings the task to the front, but then adds a new inbox activity on top of the stack.  So pressing BACK once goes back to the view message activity, and back again to the inbox activity.

I also tried setting different properties such as singleTask for my inbox activity in the app manifest, but haven't had any luck.  Is this a known issue that flags are not saved with shortcuts?

I think I'll try adding a new stub activity that does nothing but launches the real activity with the NEW_TASK flag and then exits, and have my shortcuts point to that instead. However, seems like a lot of overhead, so hopefully someone has a better answer.